# Expect window.open in WebdriverIO?

Tags: selenium, webdriver-io

Is it possible listen for a popup triggered with `window.open`? I don't care about whats inside the window, I just want to expect it to open. In Cypress it would be something like this

```
cy.window().then((win) => {
  cy.stub(win, 'open', () => {}).as('popup');
});

button.click(); // triggers the `window.open`

cy.get('@popup').should('be.called');
```

I can't quite find something like this for WebdriverIO.

Comment: Do you just want to create a new tab  ?

Comment: `window.open` with `target="_blank"` always opens a new window so I want to look for a new window being opened

Comment: in Selenium they are windows handles. I think you are looking the solution in Javascript right ?

Comment: Ah okey! Yea, that's right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
browser.getWindowHandles().length
```

this will give number of windows or tabs opened currently . use length >1 to validate window is opened