# Webdriver.io: Problems when switching to new window/tab

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, automation, webdriver-io

I'm using **Webdriver.io/Nodejs/Mocha** and when I try to switch from parent tab to child tab, majority of the time it works; however, there are times that the tab will take a long time to load  due to issues/bad adverts on the page and during those times, even though I get the window/tab GUID, it still doesn't switch and remains on the parent tab. It doesn't happen all the time but occassionally it fails to switch.

Does the page fully have to load to be able to switch to the chid tab? Am I missing anything? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

- Node version: **v16.13.1**
- WebdriverIO version: **7.16.12**
- Mocha version: **9.0.0**
- Chromedriver version: **95.0.0**

Execution:

```
npx mocha --config ./mocharc.json ./test/test.js
```

Test File: test.js

```
it('Test Case: Switch Tabs', async () => {

  let parentGUID;
  let childGUID;

  // get parent GUID
  parentGUID = await this.driver.getWindowHandle();

  // click element to launch new tab
  await this.driver.elementClick('//a[@id="test"]');

  // wait until new tab loads
  await this.driver.pause(2000);

  // get all GUID's
  const allGUIDs = await this.driver.getWindowHandles();

  // check all GUID's and see which one is the child
  for (let i = 0; i < allGUIDs.length; i++) {
    if (allGUIDs[i] !== parentGUID) {
      childGUID = allGUIDs[i];
    }
  }

  // switch to child tab
  await this.driver.switchToWindow(childGUID);

  // assert content on the new page here
  // ...
  // ...
  // ...

  // close tab
  await this.driver.closeWindow();

  // switch to parent window/tab
  await this.driver.switchToWindow(parentGUID);
}
```

Comment: Is the value of allGUIDs.length consistent?

Comment: @raju It is always consistent. It shows an array of 2. The parent tab as well as the child tab.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a simple coding mistake. While you are initiating your parentGUID, you are not assigning any value to it. You are then using it to compare in your for loop. Sometimes, the childGUID is assigned with parent GUID. In this case, the switch seems to be not happening. I have corrected it below.

```js
it('Test Case: Switch Tabs', async () => {

  let childGUID;

  // get parent GUID
  const parentGUID = await this.driver.getWindowHandle();

  // click element to launch new tab
  await this.driver.elementClick('//a[@id="test"]');

  // wait until new tab loads
  await this.driver.pause(2000);

  // get all GUID's
  const allGUIDs = await this.driver.getWindowHandles();

  // check all GUID's and see which one is the child
  for (let i = 0; i < allGUIDs.length; i++) {
    if (allGUIDs[i] !== parentGUID) {
      childGUID = allGUIDs[i];
    }
  }

  // switch to child tab
  await this.driver.switchToWindow(childGUID);

  // assert content on the new page here
  // ...
  // ...
  // ...

  // close tab
  await this.driver.closeWindow();

  // switch to parent window/tab
  await this.driver.switchToWindow(parentGUID);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @raju. I tried it with what you mentioned which is the correct approach and I am still getting the same problem. I noticed it's because the page loads indefinitey.. Is there any way I can make webdriverio not care if the tab has loaded and switch to it?

Comment: Hey! I have been checking on this one but could not reproduce this. The app you are testing is private? if it public, could you share the link?

Comment: unfortunately it is private and there is no way I can share it. I will see if I can try to figure it out but essentially when we open up a new tab, it loads indefinitely (sometimes) and I cannot use the GUID to switch over to the child tab. I suppose if you want to try to reproduce it, use the code I pasted up above and try to access a heavy site full of ads and repeat 20 times. Let me know if you see any tabs that take a long time to load and also let me know if you are able to successfully switch over to the child.

Answer (score 0):

For indefinite loading tab you can wait on the number of tabs open(including the tab you want to switch to) then you can switch to the new tab.

```
browser.waitUntil(async function(){
              return (await browser.getWindowHandles()).length==3; 
              
         },{timeout:30000});
```

Then you can switch to new tab:

```
await browser.switchWindow("TITLE_OF_YOUR_TAB");
```

see below links for reference:

[getWindowHandles-wdio docs](https://webdriver.io/docs/api/webdriver/#getwindowhandle)

[SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68192900/expect-window-open-in-webdriverio)

[waitUntil-wdio docs](https://webdriver.io/docs/api/browser/waitUntil)